# How do I count values from two different tables based off a id from another table in one query?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to count the amount of `users` and `channel_memberships` that have a `channel_partner_id` for each channel from the `channel_partners` table.

I want to run these two queries in one query:

```
SELECT channel_partners.id,
    channel_partners.name,
    COUNT(channel_memberships.channel_partner_id) AS membership_count
    
FROM channel_partners
JOIN channel_memberships ON channel_partners.id = channel_memberships.channel_partner_id

GROUP BY channel_partners.id
```

and

```
SELECT channel_partners.id,
    channel_partners.name,
    COUNT(users.channel_partner_id) AS user_count
    
FROM channel_partners
JOIN users ON channel_partners.id = users.channel_partner_id

GROUP BY channel_partners.id
```

I've tried to do this:

```
SELECT channel_partners.id,
    channel_partners.name,
    COUNT(users.channel_partner_id) AS user_count,
    COUNT(channel_memberships.channel_partner_id) AS membership_count
    
FROM channel_partners
JOIN users ON channel_partners.id = users.channel_partner_id 
JOIN channel_memberships ON channel_partners.id = channel_memberships.channel_partner_id


GROUP BY channel_partners.id
```

When I run this both `user_count` and `membership_count` are equal and have values that are vastly different from when I run the two queries individually. For example when ran individually, for the channel_partner with id 20 I get 1178 user_count, 12588 membership_count, and when I run both together I get user_count and membership_count equaling 14828664 for the channel_partner with id 20.

Comment: Try Unionising the two queries, or possibly try setting them both as subqueries? I'm not sure which would be best. Or maybe `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN` on your tables that don't appear on both queries?

Comment: Using `LEFT JOIN` gives the same results. I'm looking up how to use subqueries now.

Comment: what about using counts on subqueries? 

SELECT channel_partners.id, 
(SELECT COUNT(users.blah)) as user_count,
(SELECT COUNT(members.blah)) as membership_count
FROM etc etc

then I think you don't need the JOINS

Comment: Yes, okay, using subqueries has worked exactly as intended. I'm somewhat new to stack overflow, how do I mark a comment as the answer or should I answer my own question? Thank you for help.

Comment: tbh I don't think you can mark a comment as an answer (it even says dont answer in a comment) so I reckon answer yourself for future lookups i.e. give your working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Martin and Nick in the comments for helping me solve this. I can use subqueries instead of joins.

This is the working query here:

```
SELECT channel_partners.id,
    channel_partners.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(users.channel_partner_id)
        FROM users
        WHERE users.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id) AS user_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(channel_memberships.channel_partner_id)
        FROM channel_memberships
        WHERE channel_memberships.channel_partner_id = channel_partners.id) AS membership_count
    
FROM channel_partners
```